# Developing a database driven android app for insurance quoting

Tags: android, database, excel, sqlite

A couple of years ago I created a spreadsheet in Excel that allowed an insurance agent to input some data about a client (e.g. Age, Sex, Smoker?, zip code, Rate class) and have the spreadsheet populate about a dozen fields with the rates for multiple product lines and multiple companies. Each company had its own worksheet that contained all of the rating information that the main screen would pull the data from. I used many "vlookup", "if", "and", "or" functions to achieve this

I would like to turn this into an Android app but I have not been able to find any sort of a tutorial that would get me started.

What I have figured out is that I will need to simplify and convert my spreadsheet into a sqlite database. I have found tutorials that discuss reading that info and displaying it as lists and so forth.

Where I'm stumped is how to incorporate the many functions I use to look up the specific data. So if anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You have to fire the queries for that. For eg; if you want to get data by filtering then you can use functions available that is between, like, sort, max, min, etc.... see this links
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android
So you need to use the function available in sqlite as per your requirement....Hope this may help you....

Comment: just use sql as far as your knowledge goes and do the rest in java. I personally find the sqlite page http://www.sqlite.org/ very useful . http://vogella.de as Scorpion already pointed out is awesome for getting a first clear overview about how things work in android - and yes the official android documentation is very good too